# How to subscribe to multiple events

Tags: c#, .net, events, .net-core, event-handling

I have a `UserGroup` object that has a property: List of `User` objects. Each `User` object raises particular event. I want to be able to handle this event from all `Users` in `UserGroup`.

For example:

```
public abstract class User : IUser
{
    public event EventHandler<MatchCompletedEventArgs> MatchCompleted;

    public bool Match(Job job)
    {
        bool result = UserMatch(job);

        EventHandler<MatchCompletedEventArgs> handler = MatchCompleted;
        handler?.Invoke(this, new MatchCompletedEventArgs(result));

        return result;
    }

    protected abstract bool UserMatch(Job job);
}


public class UserGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<IUser> Users { get; set; }

    public UserGroup(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Users = new List<IUser>();
    }

    public void AddUser(IUser user)
    {
        // TODO:
        // In here I want to subscribe to user.MatchCompleted event 
        // Eventually I want to be able to handle MatchCompleted event in all users in the list

        Users.Add(user);
    }

    public void OnMatchCompleted()
    {
        // TODO:
        // Whenever, any of the users throws MatchCompleted completed event I need to store complex informations about the Match process,
        // Ideally in one place, like this function.
    }

    public bool Match(Job job)
    {
        // Match will return TRUE only if all users will match it
        foreach (var user in Users)
        {
            if (!user.Match(job)) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

These two *"TODO"* in the code is what I'm looking for.

How can I catch an event that can be raised by multiple objects stored in one list?

Comment: The "complex information" should go in your `MatchCompletedEventArgs` class. That can include a reference to the `User` object so you can just subscribe to the one event.

Comment: Think of like a `ListView`. You'd have an event on the `ListView` that was `ItemAdded` and the EventArgs class for that event would include which item was added. You wouldn't have an event on the item you added itself that triggered when it was added to the `ListView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subcribe to the event for each `User` object in the method which is pretty straightforward :

```
public void AddUser(IUser user)
{
    user.MatchCompleted  += OnMatchCompleted; // subscribed event for each user       
    Users.Add(user);
}
```

and your event would look like:

```
public void OnMatchCompleted(object sender,MatchCompletedEventArgs e)
{   
    User user = sender as User;   // will work fine
    IUser iUser = sender as IUser; // this will also work

   // now you can use user information
   // write your complex logic here
}
```

Now this way `OnMatchCompleted` will be called for every user in the collection of `Users` as we subscribed for each of them.

Comment: Thanks! Looks pretty straight forward. Hmm... Is there any concurrency/multi-thread warning?

Comment: @IshThomas didn't get your question, is it running in multithreading

Comment: I meant, in OnMatchCompleted, should I care about potential deadlocks? What if two users complete their matches in the same time? Obviously, it won't happen in my example, as I have a simple `foreach` loop, but what If I have parallel foreach?

Comment: @IshThomas if you run parallel loop in that case as well each one will run in it's separately